# Read username in WCF service after authenticate

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, authentication

I have a custom validator   that validate the incoming username and password in a webservice .
Once the validation is done, i need to  use that user name  and password inside the webservice .
Here is my CustomValidator

```
  public class ServiceAuthenticator : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger("ServiceAuthenticator");
        public override void Validate(String userName, string password)
        {

            _log.InfoFormat("-------------{0}/{1}------------------------------", userName, password);

           if (userName == null || password == null)
            {
                _log.WarnFormat("  Missing User-name / Password  {0}/{1}", userName, password);
                throw new FaultException("Incorrect User name or Password");
           
            }

        }
    }
```

Now i have a webservice where i am trying to get the above user name and password

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "Uplooc")]
    [WebMethod(Description = "Save documents ")]
     public  void UploadDocGen(RemoteFileInfo remoteFileInfo)
        {
           // string UserName = ""; --- How i get the username
           // sting Password  = "";  -- How to get the password into this 
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use the [`ServiceSecurityContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext) to obtain the username value, while we could not get the password after the credential is authenticated to pass.

```
public string SayHello()
{
    OperationContext oc = OperationContext.Current;
    var username1=oc.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
    Console.WriteLine(username1);
    var username2 = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
    Console.WriteLine(username2);
    return $"Hello Buddy,{DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
}
```

**Result.**
[image]
The security token based on the SAML, we only can obtain the claim sets. It is a complex topic, which I don’t know much.
Here are some related documents, wish it is useful to you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-examine-the-security-context
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext?view=netframework-4.8
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: thank you very much. This gave the Username. Now trying to find the password  from the context